# AWS AutoScaling with Static IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to do AutoScaling with Static IPs in AWS ? The newly created instances should either have a pre-defined IP or pick from a pool of pre-defined IPs.

We are trying to setup ZooKeeper in production, with 5 zooKeeper instances. Each one should have a static-IP which are to hard-coded in the Kafka's AMI/Databag that we use. It should also support AutoScaling, so that if one of the zooKeeper node goes down, a new one is spawned with the same IP or from a pool of IPs. For this we have decided to go with 1 zoo-keeper instance per AutoScaling group, but the problem is with the IP.

If this is the wrong way, please suggest the right way. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to maintain a [user data script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) on each instance, and have each instance assign itself an [elastic IPs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) from a set of EIPs assigned for this purpose. This user data script would be referenced in the ASGs Launch Configuration, and would run on launch.

Say the user script is called "/scripts/assignEIP.sh", using the AWS CLI you would have it consult the pool to see which ones are available and which ones are not (already in use). Then it would assign itself one of the available EIPS.

For ease of IP management, you could keep the pool of IPs in a simple text properties file on S3, and have the instance download and consult that list when the instance starts.

Keep in mind that each instance will need an to be assigned IAM instance profile that will allow each instance to consult and assign EIPs to itself.

Comment: thanks, let me try it out. How do i change the IP of an instance ? Does AWS have any scripts for that ?

Comment: Use the AWS CLI: `aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id i-43a4412a --allocation-id eipalloc-64d5890a` See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html